# How to set default @AuthenticationPrincipal on startup

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

For development purpose, I am trying to configure a `development` profile for which developers don't need to be authenticated in the application to call REST services.

But, some of these services need an `@AuthenticationPrincipal` to work.
So I would like to be able to define a mocked `@AuthenticationPrincipal` on startup to be used by default.

Does anyone have any kind of idea to do so?

Currently the application behavior expected for the user authentication is:

- A REST endpoint should send a HTTP code 401 if the user isn't authenticated.
- In this case, the Front-end should redirect the user to the back-end URL `/login` so that he can authenticate itself.
- On success, the back-end should then redirect the user to the front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out that it wasn't a good solution, here a list of the different reasons I can think of:

1. The behavior of the back-end server would be different between the development and the production environments.
2. This would force the front-end to also have different behaviors between these two environments.
3. JUnits wouldn't be able to test all expected answers (example: HTTP code 401 if not authenticated) from endpoints.

So in place, I have created a security configuration (enabled only when not using the production profile) emulating the expected behavior from the front-end point of view.

Here the `MockAuthenticationSecurityConfiguration` class:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!PRODUCTION")
public class MockAuthenticationSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    public MockAuthenticationSecurityConfiguration(final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties) {
        this.applicationProperties = applicationProperties;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("swagger-ui.html").permitAll();
        // All API REST endpoint can only be accessed by an authenticated user.
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                // For these REST endpoint to answer HTTP code 401 in place of redirecting the user to /login.
                .and().exceptionHandling().defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(new Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint(), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"))
                // On success, we want to redirect the user to a specific URL (the frontend).
                .and().formLogin().permitAll().successHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler(applicationProperties.getRedirectUrl()))
                .and().logout().permitAll()
        ;
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // Add a mocked user to be used to authenticate.
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("jdoe").password("jdoe").roles("USER"));
    }

}
```

Here the `Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint` class:

```
public class Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
    }
}
```

And then the `ApplicationProperties` class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("application")
public class ApplicationProperties {

    /**
     * The URL to which we should redirect the user once he is logged in the application.
     */
    private String redirectUrl;

}
```